# Stop disappearing ModalPopup panel (shown by ModalPopupExtender ) on changing text of a textbox (TextChanged event fired by AutoPostback)

Tags: modalpopupextender, autopostback

I have a html table inside of a panel control.
It will be shown by a ModalPopupExtender by clicking on a LinkButton.

inside of the panel, there is a textbox which its "AutoPostBack" property is Ture and when user enters a value in it, TextChanged event is fired but unfortunately, the panel also disapears.....

what's wrong?